# Switch case instead of if else

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

How is it possible to switch this code into a `switch` case?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("w");
    else if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 2)
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    else if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 3)
        Console.WriteLine("s");
    else if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 4)
        Console.WriteLine("d");

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

This is my last try and the line on the first case is again marked as red

```
switch (m.Msg)
{
    case m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 1:
       Console.WriteLine("w");
       break;
    case m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 2:
       Console.WriteLine("a");
       break;
    case m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 3:
       Console.WriteLine("s");
       break;
    case m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == 4:
       Console.WriteLine("d");
       break;
}
```

Is this possible? I think it would look better to read inside a `switch` statement.

Comment: You are using multiple logical operators in your conditional statement which cannot be converted to a switch statement

Comment: Do you need to handle only this WM_HOTKEY case or you have others message types to handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot switch on the condition. You can only switch on constant values.

```
if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
{
    switch ((int)m.WParam)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("w");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("s");
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("d");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the value of `Msg` is always the same (in your conditions), you could try this:

```
if(m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
{
    switch ((int)m.WParam)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("w");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("a");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("s");
            break;
        case 4:
            Console.WriteLine("d");
            break;
    }
}
```

It is important to realize the following (taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)) regarding the `switch` statement:

> Each case label **specifies a constant value**. The switch statement
>   transfers control to the switch section whose case label matches the
>   value of the switch expression (caseSwitch in the example). If no case
>   label contains a matching value, control is transferred to the default
>   section, *if there is one*. If there is no default section, no action is
>   taken and control is transferred outside the switch statement.

Comment: Thank you too for your help. The solution works great. :)

Comment: @user3772108 You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use logical operators in switch case. It operates on only a single value

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do here is this:

```
if(m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
{
    var param = (int)m.WParam;
    switch(param)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("w");
            break;
            ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
    {
        var param = (int)m.WParam;
        switch (param)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("w");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("a");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("s");
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.WriteLine("d");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unrecognised key stroke.");
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    // todo:  What if m.Msg is no WM_HOTKEY?
}
```